# Error while configuring Openldap Master-Slave replication

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-14.04, replication, openldap

While replicating openldap Master-Slave, I stuck in the middle and tried to resolve but is not working. Using Ubuntu14.04 OS, I'm following this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/360190/how-to-configure-master-slave-ldap-replication

In the second step "enable_sync_prov.ldif" I'm getting this error:

```
modifying entry "olcDatabase={0}hdb,cn=config"

ldap_modify: No such object (32)

matched DN: cn=config
```

I tried changing `olcDatabase={1}` mdb and bdb, still getting the same error.

Please someone help me.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This question is not relative to development. You should try to post it on serverfault. When you do, try as much as possible to add informations useful to determine what is the problem (configuration of your directory, command used to import the ldif, DIT, etc)

Comment: Are you using online configuration (`slapd -F`)? If not, you have to modify `slapd.conf`, not try to modify the non-existent online configuration. Otherwise you need to provide the `ldapmodify` command line you're using. And you're off topic.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. Sorry for posting this question in irrelevant forum. Can you please explain a bit on how to that modifications?